# constexpr C++ container – a way to push_back to initializer_list or similar

Tags: c++, stdvector, initializer-list, stdarray, string-view

This function parses input line into argument like shell(bash,ksh,fish) does. I.e. looks in input string parts separated by whitespaces or tabs:

```
auto parse_args(string_view const& line){
    vector<string_view> args;
    size_t pos_begin = 0, pos_end = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (pos_end < line.size() && pos_end != string_view::npos) {
        pos_begin = line.find_first_not_of(" \t", pos_end);
        if (pos_begin == string_view::npos)
            break;
        pos_end = line.find_first_of(" \t", pos_begin);
        if (pos_end == string_view::npos)
            pos_end = line.size();
        args.emplace_back(line.substr(pos_begin, pos_end - pos_begin));
        i++;
    }
    return args;
}
```

Result is a set of views into input string - `vector<string_view>`. Input is not changed.
Looking at C++17's `string_view` I've found most of functions are `constexpr`. In my function only `vector::push_back()` executed at runtime. So I solved to make `parse_args()` `constexpr`, need to replace `std::vector` with constexpr container.
I looked for a way to append to `initializer_list` or better to say create new initializer_list on top of previous one, but with no success. 
**Please suggest a way** to "push_back" to `initializer_list` or `std::array` or similar constexpr container. I do not look for any big third-party library.

Comment: I don't think you can convert this function to constexpr. This would require argument to be known at compile time.

Comment: @user7860670 Argument is known at compile-time. And this is why I want to turn it into constexpr.

Comment: But in the question you wrote "This function parses input line" and input is never known at compile time. Also if argument is indeed known at compile time then you probably can populate output array directly instead of writing parsing function.

Comment: This cannot be done in C++17 with the interface you seem to want, but if you are willing to wait for it to be implemented, the function can be marked `constexpr` as is in C++20.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is running on command-line args, there's little to no benefit of making this constexpr. If it's truly used with non-`constexpr` `char*`s, then it'd be impossible to call anyway.

For most application code, going far out of the way for `constexpr` is probably superfluous.

That being said, you could define an `std::array` with a specified upper bound (say, 1000), and assume that you don't overflow.